# Is there a connection between exact differentials and law of total probability?

Tags: probability, derivatives

The law of total probability is in general:
$$P(A)=\sum_n P(A\mid B_n)P(B_n)$$

You can express a differential of a function in the following sum:

$$\text{d}f = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{df(x_1,x_2,...,x_i)}{dx_i} \,dx_i$$

These two expressions look quite similar, and is about summing terms that are in some sense 'disjoint'. Like a decomposition of of an 'object' (I don't know how I would call it) in its disjoint terms. It's almost like $x_i$ is like a partition similar to $B_n$. Is there a direct relation? Or is there actual no similarity at all? I hope there is some insight to be gained.

Comment: Your expression for $\mathrm df$ is not correct, currently it's just a sum of $f(x_i)$. Also, what does it mean: *example for two partitions would be*?

Comment: thanks for you suggestings, i corrected them

Comment: What about $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_i) = f(x_i)$? Are those different functions on a different number of arguments? Why are they all denoted as $f$?

Comment: I suspect the law of total probability is more akin to Riemann sum in that if $B_{n,k} = \{nX \in (k-1, k]\}$ then $P(Y \in A) = \sum_k P(Y \in A \mid B_{n,k}) P(B_{n,k})$ for a random variable in $X \in [0, 1].$ The right hand side will converge to $\int P(Y \in A \mid X = x) f_X(x) dx$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: I think what Ilya was talking about is that you probably meant to have *partial* derivatives of $f$ rather than total derivatives. $$\mathrm{d}f = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}{\partial x_i} \,\mathrm{d}x_i$$